# SQL Connection: Cannot open server "example.com" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, connection-string

I am attempting to establish a connection to SQL Server with this connection string:

```
new SqlConnection("Server=tcp:myServer.net,1433;Database=myDatabase;
Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
User Id=user123@example.com;Password=SomePassword123")
       .Open();
```

But I keep getting this error. It's like it doesn't respect the `@` symbol as part of the username. I tried single quotes, double quotes, and two `@@` symbols to see if any of that would escape it but still gives this error about the domain name. It's just part of the username.

```
Class: 20
    ClientConnectionId: {b9d66561-5e69-4a01-840d-86eb9b3066f9}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    ErrorCode: -2146232060
    Errors: {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlErrorCollection}
    HResult: -2146232060
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    IsTransient: false
    LineNumber: 0
    Message: "Cannot open server \"example.com\" requested by the login.  The login failed."
    Number: 40532
    Procedure: ""
    Server: "tcp:myServer.net,1433"
    Source: "Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider"
    SqlState: null
    StackTrace: "   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception e)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions u
serOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()"
    State: 1
```

Comment: One thing to note is I used this same connection string with the .NET Core DB Scaffolding tool and it worked fine. In that scenario I just had on extra option of `Authentication=` specified for that string but the SQL Connection says it is not supported here for this error.

Comment: You could try replacing the `@` with `&commat;`?

Comment: That gives `"Login failed for user 'user123&commat;example.com'."`

Comment: Is `STRING_ESCAPE` an option?

Comment: I tried adding `STRING_ESCAPE=true;` to the end of the string but said that keyword is not supported.

Comment: Just for giggles, have you tried `User Id=user123@example.com@myServer.net;` yet?

Comment: `user123@example.com` if this is a Windows login then you are doing this wrong. You should not pass in username and password at all, just set `Trusted Connection=True`. Windows will pass through the username and password hash or token automatically

Comment: To be honest, I think it probably is a Windows Authentication login. Because `@` doesn't actually need escaping. If you use `SqlConnectionBuilder` you will see that

Comment: I added the trusted connection and removed the user/pass options @Charlieface and it says "Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server." It is an Azure managed database but we do use AD to login to stuff like the DB using SSMS.  I can confirm we are using the `DbContextOptionsBuilder` to create the connection.

Comment: `System.Data.SqlClient` doesn't support Azure at all, you need a newer library `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` and you need to add `Authentication=Active Directory Password;` to your connection string, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15